# Как добавить реплику к команде бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

У меня вопрос, как я могу добавить реплику к команде бота? Поясняю.

```
@dp.message_handler(text='обнять')
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
  if message.reply_to_message:
      await message.answer(f'  | @{message.from_user.username} обнял(-а) @{message.reply_to_message.from_user.username}\nРеплика: {message.text}')
  else:
    pass
```

Вывод:
 | @Юзер обнял(-а) @Юзер
Реплика: обнять

Как я могу сделать чтобы человек писал, допустим:

```
Обнять
бро
```

И ему выводилось что он обнял с репликой бро? Ничего на ум не приходит.
Помогите пожолуйста

Comment: я немного не понял. если честно, но если хотите реакцию на Обнять бро.. можно в логику кода добавить что-то типа: if message.text == 'Обнять бро': дальнейшая логика

Comment: Нет, в место бро человек может написать что угодно. пример есть в боте ирис. Т.е
Пишет обнять ты красивый, а вывод юзер обнял юзер с репликой ты красивый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.split(' ')
    if message.reply_to_message:
        if text[0] == 'обнять':
            text.pop(0)
            new_text = ' '.join(text)
            await message.answer(f'  | @{message.from_user.username} обнял(-а) @{message.reply_to_message.from_user.username}\nРеплика: {new_text}')
    else:
      pass
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вывод:
  юзер обнял(-а) юзер
Реплика: о б н я т ь

Comment: вроде исправил, пробуйте

Comment:  | юзер обнял(-а) юзер
Реплика:

Если обнимать с репликой, сообщение вообще не выводится

Comment: ну хватит... у вас все козыри на руках, проще только яблоки собирать.

Comment: сработало? я проверил несколько раз, обновленный код точно должен работать

Comment: Да! Спасибо большое! Только теперь нужно доработать команду под себя